# Git removing commiter information

Tags: git, version-control

I started some project on github.com. And I'm working on two machines. I did something like this:

1. Create project on github,
2. Clone project form github on Machine1,
3. Did some commits on Machine1,
4. Created reposytory on Machine2,
5. Push changes from Machine1 to Machine2 and github.

Next day I was working on Machine2. I have different configs there so I was doing commits with  "--author=something" param. After finishing work I pushed my changes to Machine1.

I pushed my changes from Machine1 to github. And I can see that commits done on Machine1 have in history filed Author which is correct and also Committer filed which is from Machine1. And I don't want to public this Commiter filed. How I can remove it?

Temporarily I did on Machine1:

```
git reset --hard <commit before changes on Machine1>
git push -f github master
```

But it looks like that getting committer information is still possible. How to remove it permanently.

Best regards,

Adam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to change committer information, you can use [`git rebase`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) which takes your commits and replays them on top of another commit. The `--no-ff` option is important here, as it ensures that every commit will be recreated. Otherwise git will fast-forward in case when the rebase would be a no-op.

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=Adam;
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=adam@example.com;
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME;
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL;
git rebase --no-ff <commit before changes on Machine1>
```

This will quickly get tricky when your history is a bit more complex (merges), in that case it might be better to use filter-branch.

If you also want to change author information, use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) and rewrite all of your commits with `--env-filter`. be sure to have a backup in case my command is flawed ;) – though I do not hope so

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=Adam;
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=adam@example.com;
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME;
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL;

git commit-tree "$@";
' <commit before changes on Machine1>..HEAD
```

you can also use `--all` instead of a refspec to rewrite all commits in your repository

nb: that's a bad thing to do if you have shared your repository already and you will have to re-clone it on every machine you want to work with it.